Reflecting Disk Size change in IaC
For Context: We did run out of Diskspace on one of our VM's, so I increased the Disk Space via the Google Cloud Console (Web Browser) to quickly fix the issue based on this Doc: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk?hl=en
But as we actually have an IaC Repository I wanted to reflect the Change in our IaC, but when doing so by executing the command:
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update infrastructure --config deployment.yaml
I got the following error:
{ "ResourceType": "gcp-types/compute-v1:disks", "ResourceErrorCode": "400", "ResourceErrorMessage": { "code": 400, "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "message": "Invalid value for field 'sizeGb': '500'. New disk size '500' GiB must be larger than existing size '500' GiB.", "reason": "invalid" } ], "message": "Invalid value for field 'sizeGb': '500'. New disk size '500' GiB must be larger than existing size '500' GiB.", "statusMessage": "Bad Request", "requestPath": "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/not-your-business/zones/europe-west6-a/disks/server-data/resize", "httpMethod": "POST" } }

I was looking for a flag to reflect the changes already made on console


I am not sure about your case, but be careful with resources. Terraform might recreate the entire instance which could result in data loss.
